# Converting StringJoin to StringForm inside Hold

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation, hold

Let's say I have a piece of code:

```
Hold[{code1,
      "asdad " <> ToString[testa] <> " adsd " <> ToString[testb],
      code2}] (*MWE ofc*)
```

which I want to convert. Each `StringJoin[...]` should be replaced so I will get:

> ```
> Hold[{code1, StringForm["asdad `` adsd ``", testa, testb], code2}]
> ```

I have an answer but maybe one may show shorter approach:

```
Hold[{code1, "asdad " <> ToString[testa] <> " adsd " <> ToString[testb], code2}
    ] /. HoldPattern[StringJoin[x__]
                    ] :> RuleCondition@(
          StringForm[StringJoin @@ (Hold[x] /. _ToString :> "``"), 
                     ##] & @@ Cases[Hold[x], HoldPattern[ToString[z_]] :> z]
          ) // InputForm
```

> ```
>  Hold[{code1, StringForm["asdad `` adsd ``", testa, testb], code2}]
> ```

**Edit:** This solution is not perfect. It evauates `testa` and `testb`, does not matter in my case but for generality let's assume they may **not be evaluated.** Also, referring to first of Mr.Wizard's suggestions: **`StringJoin` expressions may appear or different levels** too.

Comment: Should all `StringJoin` objects be replaced, or only those at level 2, or only certain ones by position?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Let's say we don't know on which level they may appear. But if you have neat solution for the simpler case, I'm lookng forward seeing it too.

Comment: I was trying to solve this on my own, without reading your solution, but I struggled to get evaluation correct so I looked at your method to see how you had solved it.  I discovered that your code does not work properly: `testa` and `testb` get evaluated.  Is that acceptable?

Comment: I think I'm remembering something.  Please tell me, what are the `Attributes` of `StringForm` on  your system?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard only `Protected`. Hmm, it seems they are, I've missed that because it does not make a difference for my purposes.

Comment: Okay.  Would you make clear in the question whether it does or does not matter?  I'll adjust my code to match.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ok, done. let me eat the dinner and I will check answers :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that in general, for tasks like this one, tricks like Trott-Strzebonski technique are not the best way, and one really needs expression parsers, which are may be not shorter, but more readable and more extensible. Here is a possible one for your problem:

```
ClearAll[convert];
SetAttributes[convert, {HoldAll}];
convert[x_List] := Map[convert, Unevaluated[x]];
convert[Hold[{pieces___}]] :=
   (Hold[#] &[convert[{pieces}]]) /. convert[x_] :> x;
convert[s_StringJoin] := convertSJ[s];
```

where the specific converter for `StringJoin` is:

```
ClearAll[convertSJ];
SetAttributes[convertSJ, HoldAll];
convertSJ[s_StringJoin] := convertSJ[s, {}];
convertSJ[StringJoin[prev__String, ToString[x_], rest___], {accum___}] :=
   convertSJ[StringJoin[prev, " `` ", rest], {accum, x}];
convertSJ[s_StringJoin, {accum___}] := 
   With[{st = s}, convert[StringForm[st, accum]]];
```

So that

```
convert[
  Hold[{code1, "asdad " <> ToString[testa] <> " adsd " <> ToString[testb], code2}]
]

(* Hold[{code1, StringForm["asdad  ``  adsd  `` ", testa, testb], code2}] *)
```

Comment: I was about to ask "why" but then I remembered we've been over this before.  Frankly I still don't agree, as that `convert` with all its cases seems more confusing to me than a single replacement rule that caries out a specific action.  "Agree to disagree" I guess.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The big advantage of `convert` is that its rules are composable, which means that, for more complex expressions, it will automatically dispatch to a right rule for a given part, and then combine them all together again. The difference in power between plain rule-based approach and the one based on parsers is pretty much similar to a difference between a parser and a regexp, for string parsing (with a caveat that patterns in M are more powerful than regexps). The more complex the original expression and the transformation rules, the more this difference will show.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Another reason why I prefer this approach is that in every single rule in `convert`, I can focus on only what this particular rule should do. In a single rule a-la your solution or others, all these transformations are coupled together by the evaluation control constructs, while in my approach evaluation control does not couple the transformation together. If I want to change that rule later, for example, I don't have to care what else such a change might break.

Comment: The first point I *think* I understand, but I'll think about it (again).  If one knows *from the start* that this operation will not transmogrify into something more complicated do you still feel that a parser is the best approach?  How do you decide when it is appropriate to leave behind simple rules and start using a parser?  Do you have to write out your parser code by hand every time, or do you have some meta-code for this?

Comment: Would you please amplify *"In a single rule a-la your solution or others, all these transformations are coupled together by the evaluation control constructs, while in my approach evaluation control does not couple the transformation together."*  Again, I *think* I understand what you're saying, and I *think* I start to see the superiority of the parser, but I need a lot of help I guess. :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, I still think that the parser approach is still superior even in that case, because I find it easier to understand. In most (but not all) cases, I started to view TZ trick as a hack, and when you need something more complicated that what TZ gives out of the box (in terms of evaluation), you need more hacks to make it all work without evaluation leaks. The parser approach is straight-forward: you descend down the expression, transform, and then collect the expression back, with evaluation control taken care of explicitly in each case.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard And if there is an evaluation leak, it is localized to a single rule, which you can fix. And again, it allows you to focus on a single rule at a time, and then the problem of evaluation control does not get worse when you deal with more complex rules / expressions.

Comment: You have *almost* convinced me but I still have trouble finding this easy to read.  Would you consider posting a self Q&A with a graphical illustration of a simple parser?  I think I lack a mental image that allows me to "see" this operation.  I hope you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: Also, any reason for `(Hold[#] &[convert[{pieces}]])` rather than the shorter `Hold @@ {convert[{pieces}]}`?  (Or even `Hold @@ convert[{pieces}]`?)  Is the single argument (use of `Slot`) significant?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Re: self-answer - would like to, but right now my time here is over, need to finish something. Hope to remember to do this later. Re: `Hold`: your first version is a possible alternative, I am just used to `Hold[#]&` idiom, and I like it because it makes it explicit that we want to leak evaluation here. Your last option (`Hold @@ ...`) will leak evaluation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ok, one last thing I did for now was to factor out the conversion for `StringJoin` pieces, since it is in fact not really coupled with the rest of `convert`. This seems to make the code a bit easier to read.

Comment: Thanks Leonid.  I do hope you have time for the Q&A later.  By the way, if `Hold @@ convert[{pieces}]` leaks doesn't the following rule `/. convert[x_] :> x` cause the same problem?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I will really try to remember posting this, since this seems to be an important topic, and I feel that expression parsers are a powerful technique. Re: `convert` - the rule `convert[x_]:>x` does not leak because by the time it is applied, expression is dressed back in `Hold`. It is implicitly assumed here that `Hold` is the top-level wrapper of entire expression, and the starting (end ending) point of the application of `convert`.

Comment: btw, congrats on 50k! Half way there to a 100k :)

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks, man :). Now I joined the 50K club :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin May I ask additional questions? Let's say there is "1/2" in the row, but in 2D form. Is there any way to avoid conversion to "\(!\(...", while preserving input form of possible `Style["1/2", Bold]`? I can ask a separate question later if you want.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, please ask a separate one. I am currently out of context for this problem, and the cost of context switching is too high for me at the moment.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Of course :) I will do this in near future. Good luck with your current duties :)

Answer (score 1):

An embedded [Trott-Strzebonski method](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/villegas/UnevaluatedExpressions/Links/index_lnk_30.html)-approach. `rep[expr, held, from -> to, f]` works by:

- holding `held` symbol (like `ToString`);
- replacing symbol `from` with `to` (like `StringJoin -> StringForm`), partially evaluating arguments that are not held...
- ...applying function `f` to arguments not held in `from`.

It leaves `code...` and `test...` parts unevaluated, es expected.

```
rep[expr_, held_, from_ -> to_, f_] := Block[{z}, 
   expr //. {held -> HoldForm, from -> z} /. (z[y__] :> Block[{},
     to @@ MapThread[#1 @@ (#2 /@ #3) &,
       {{from, Sequence}, {f, #&}, GatherBy[{y}, Head]}] /; True]) //. HoldForm->held];

{code1, code2} = {11, 22};
testa := (Print@"A"; 2);
testb := (Print@"B"; 4);

rep[expr, ToString, StringJoin -> StringForm, #<>"``" &] // InputForm
```

> ```
> Hold[{code1, StringForm["asdad `` adsd ``",
>      ToString[testa], ToString[testb]], code2}]
> ```

It is general enough to deal with other types of replacements:

```
expr = Hold[{code1, 1 + N@testa + 3 + N@testb, code2}];
rep[expr, N, Plus -> g, f] // InputForm
```

> ```
> Hold[{code1, g[f[1] + f[3], N[testa], N[testb]], code2}]
> ```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Kuba Please see new version.

Comment: The new version does not prevent evaluation of `testa` and `testb`, but neither does Kuba's original.  My `rule` code seems a good deal simpler in this case.  Also your code has `ToString[testa]` rather than bare `testa`, which does not behave the same; consider for example if `testa` is a "2D" expression.  This could be an advantage or a disadvantage depending on what Kuba wants.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yeah, I've realized that too. For the moment, I don't have time to figure out something clever. If I cannot do better tomorrow, I'll delete it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Figured out something.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with.  Better?  I don't know.

```
convert =
 Block[{StringForm},
   SetAttributes[StringForm, HoldRest];
   # /. sj_StringJoin :> RuleCondition[
      Reap[Unevaluated[sj] /. (t : ToString)[x_] :> (Sow[Hold@x]; " `` "), _, 
        Join @@ #2 &] /. {s_, {_[ex__]}} :> StringForm[s, ex]]
 ] &;
```

Test:

```
start = Hold[{code1, "asdad " <> ToString[testa] <> " adsd " <> ToString[testb], code2}];
{code1, code2} = {0, 0};
testa := 2 + 2
testb := Print["!"]

convert @ start // InputForm
```

> ```
> Hold[{code1, StringForm["asdad  ``  adsd  `` ", testa, testb], code2}]
> ```

If we don't need to prevent evaluation of `testa` and `testb`, which Kuba's code does not do, we can simplify this considerably:

```
rule = sj_StringJoin :>
  RuleCondition[
   StringForm[#, Sequence @@ #2[[1]]] & @@
    Reap[Unevaluated[sj] /. ToString :> ((Sow[#]; " `` ") &)]
  ];

start /. rule // InputForm
```

> During evaluation of In[]:= !
>
> ```
> Hold[{code1, StringForm["asdad  ``  adsd  `` ", 4, Null], code2}]
> ```

Comment: This attribute is quite nice, I'm struggling with injection of unevaluated sequence in different way but I got stuck now. :p p.s. to many whitespaces: " `` " -> "``". Thanks again.