# How can I convert a Piecewise into a nested If?

Tags: function-construction, conversion

For later conversion into a programming language where `if` is the only conditional construct, I would like to convert a `Piecewise` into a nested `If` in Mathematica. For instance, how can I convert:

```
f = Piecewise[{{x^3, x < -1}, {-x^2, -1 <= x < 0}, {x, 0 <= x < 1}, {Sqrt[x], 1 <= x}}]
```

into

```
If[x < -1, x^3, If[-1 <= x < 0, -x^2, If[0 <= x < 1, x, If[1 <= x, Sqrt[x], 0]]]]
```

?

Comment: quite related: [Converting StringJoin to StringForm inside Hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40628/5478)

Answer (score 2):

Note the structure of `Piecewise`. The first element is a list of `{value, condition}` pairs and the second element is the "default" value for when no other condition applies. If you view it as a list, here's how `f` looks:

```
f /. Piecewise -> List

{{{x^3, x < -1}, {-x^2, -1 <= x < 0}, {x, 0 <= x < 1}, {Sqrt[x], 1 <= x}}, 0}
```

First, here is a recursive function to nest each list at the third position of the previous list, stopping at the deepest list.

```
nestLists[lists_] := If[Length[lists] == 1, lists[[1]], {Sequence @@ lists[[1]], nestLists[Rest[lists]]}]
```

This lets us do this:

```
nestLists[Map[Reverse,f[[1]]]
```

yielding

```
{x < -1, x^3, {-1 <= x < 0, -x^2, {0 <= x < 1, x, {1 <= x, Sqrt[x]}}}}
```

We still need to insert the default value into the third position of the deepest list, then convert the `List`s to `If`s.

```
pwti[pw_] := ReplaceAll[Insert[#, pw[[2]], ConstantArray[-1, Length[Flatten[#]]/2]] &[nestLists[Map[Reverse, pw[[1]]]]], List -> If]
```

Now the `Piecewise` can be directly converted thus:

```
pwti[f]

If[x < -1, x^3, If[-1 <= x < 0, -x^2, If[0 <= x < 1, x, If[1 <= x, Sqrt[x], 0]]]]
```

Note that this will probably be broken if any of the values or conditions contains a list...

Comment: Does anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 1):

```
ifs = Reverse /@ (f /. Piecewise -> List /. {{x__, v_}, e_} :> {x, Join[{e}, v]});
Hold @@ Quiet@(ifs //. {x___, {a__, b__}, {c__, d__}, e___} :> {x, {a, b, {c, d}}, e} /. List -> If)

(* Hold[If[x < -1, x^3, If[-1 <= x < 0, -x^2, If[0 <= x < 1, x, If[1 <= x, Sqrt[x], 0]]]]]*)
```

Comment: Try on my f3 case...

Comment: @rasher He's migrating the code, so no lists on the new platform either :)}

Comment: Just joking. Or not :)

Answer (score 1):

My quick-n-dirty (meaning pretty untested on anything but simple cases):

```
toif = With[{if = If @@@ (Reverse /@ #[[1]]), l = #[[2]]}, 
    Nest[{Insert[#[[1]], if[[Length@#[[2]] + 1]], #[[2]]], 
        Append[#[[2]], -1]} &, {if[[1]], {-1}}, Length@if - 1] //
        Insert[#[[1]], l, #[[2]]] &] &;
```

Seems a bit more robust than your solution:

```
f1 = Piecewise[{{x^3, x < -1}, {-x^2, -1 <= x < 0}, {x, 
     0 <= x < 1}, {Sqrt[x], 1 <= x}}];

f2 = Piecewise[{{x*2, x[1] == 2}, {x*3, x[2] == 3}}];

f3 = Piecewise[{{2, x == {1, 2, 3}}, {{1, 2, 3}, x == {3, 2, 1}}, {x, 
     True}}];

Column[{toif[f1],pwti[f1]," ",
        toif[f2],pwti[f2]," ",
        toif[f3],pwti[f3]}]

(*

If[x<-1,x^3,If[-1<=x<0,-x^2,If[0<=x<1,x,If[1<=x,Sqrt[x],0]]]]
If[x<-1,x^3,If[-1<=x<0,-x^2,If[0<=x<1,x,If[1<=x,Sqrt[x],0]]]]

If[x[1]==2,2 x,If[x[2]==3,3 x,0]]
0

If[x=={1,2,3},2,If[x=={3,2,1},{1,2,3},x]]
x

*)
```

I'll ponder further when lounging later, gut tells me there's an elegant way to do this.

Much prettier:

```
toif2 = Fold[Insert[#2, #1, {-1}] &, Prepend[If @@@ Reverse /@ #[[1]], #[[2]]]] &;

toif2[f3]

(* If[x == {3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 3}, If[x == {1, 2, 3}, 2, x]] *)
```

N.b.: this reorders terms, end result is the same. Completely untested - gotta go eat!

Answer (score 1):

```
pwToIf = With[{fpw = Reverse@Transpose@Internal`FromPiecewise@#}, 
              Fold[If[## & @@ #2, #] &, fpw[[1, 2]], fpw[[2 ;;]]]] &;
```

Examples:

```
pw = Piecewise[{{x^3, x < -1}, {-x^2, -1 <= x < 0}, {x, 0 <= x < 1}, {Sqrt[x], 1 <= x}}];
pwToIf@pw
(* If[x < -1, x^3, If[-1 <= x < 0, -x^2, If[0 <= x < 1, x, If[1 <= x, Sqrt[x], 0]]]] *)

pw2 = Piecewise[{{x^3, x < -1}, {-x^2, -1 <= x < 0}, {x,  0 <= x < 1}, {Sqrt[x], 1 <= x}}, 100];
pwToIf@pw2
(* If[x < -1, x^3, If[-1 <= x < 0, -x^2, If[0 <= x < 1, x, If[1 <= x, Sqrt[x], 100]]]]*)

pw3 = Piecewise[{{2, x == {1, 2, 3}}, {{1, 2, 3}, x == {3, 2, 1}}, {x, True}}]; (* rasher's f3*)
pwToIf@pw3
(* If[x == {1, 2, 3}, 2, If[x == {3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 3}, x]] *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(Fold[{Sequence @@ (Reverse@#2), #1} &, f[[2]], Reverse@f[[1]]]) /.List -> If
(*If[x < -1, x^3,If[-1 <= x < 0, -x^2, If[0 <= x < 1, x, If[1 <= x, Sqrt[x], 0]]]]*)
```